Dataform js publish() dependencies declaration produces error
I have a source file definitions/source/tiktok/advertiser.sqlx with the following declaration:
config {
    type: "declaration",
    schema: "tiktok_ads",
    name: "advertiser",
    description: "All advertising accounts from Tiktok"
}

I am trying to define a table with javascript using the below:
publish("tiktok2", {
    schema: "sample_schema",
    type: "table",
    dependencies: (["tiktok_ads.advertiser"]),
    description: "table description"
}).query(ctx => `
      SELECT
        advertiser.name AS campaign_advertiser
      FROM
        tiktok_ads.advertiser advertiser
`)

However the dependendencies propery is generating an error (Missing dependency detected: Action "the-brand-usa.sample_schema.tiktok" depends on "{"name":"tiktok_ads.advertiser","includeDependentAssertions":false}" which does not exist).
I know the table exists and the source file is declared properly because if I replace the query to use ref() then METADATA displays the dependency properly and the whole workspace compiles properly without errors.
      SELECT
        advertiser.name AS campaign_advertiser
      FROM
        ${ctx.ref("tiktok_ads", "advertiser")} advertiser


Reviewing Dataform documentation I can see that it only accepts...

the filename of the table, assertion, data source declaration, or custom SQL operation that you want to add as a dependency. You can enter multiple filenames, separated by commas.

My issue was that I was trying to provide a table name AND schema. When I update the dependency declaration to use the unique name of the data source declaration then it resolved properly.
dependencies: (["advertiser"]),

NOTE: If you don't have a data source declaration, assertion, or custom SQL operation with this specific name, then the table defaults to searching in the schema where the table is defined.
